# Installing packages for code

Tags: java

I want to use the StringUtils.repeat(String s, long n) method contained within the org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils package. How would I do this?

Questions:

1. Where is the download link for this package?
2. Where do I place the downloaded files?

Note: I don't want to install any IDE's, I just want to install the package to use with simple editors.

Comment: Those are known as libraries. `commons-lang` is one such library provided by apache. Google it and download the corresponding `jar`. Then read up on the java classpath.

Comment: Are you using Maven or any other dependency management?

Comment: No I said I am not using any IDE's. @SotiriosDelimanolis I have googled it and I get the following page: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/index.html . Which of the following links is the StringUtils.repeat method in? There are so many.

Comment: Maven is not an IDE. Those links are the javadoc of the library's packages.  You want the library containing all of those.

Comment: I have found the method http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/index.html but how do I get it?

Comment: You should read up on what javadoc is. Then you should read about what a classpath is. Then you should read about what a java archive (jar) is.

Comment: You can download the latest `Apache Commons Lang` binaries from [here](http://apache.claz.org//commons/lang/binaries/commons-lang3-3.3.2-bin.tar.gz). Then you can extract the downloaded zip and put the `commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar`(this is the jar file you would need to use the methods of `StringUtils` class) to an appropriate location. But please note that the `StringUtils` class has [3 repeat methods](http://pastebin.com/puBDS3Ab), none with a method signature mentioned in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Where to get it?

Go to http://commons.apache.org/

and pick `lang` library. You will end up in

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

where you can find latest release of `commons-lang` package (which contains [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) class you are looking for).

Download latest release of this package. To do so pick "download" from left menu which will lead you to

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Since you claim you don't want to use any IDE you probably will not need source so just download binaries. So pick either `commons-lang3-3.3.2-bin.zip` or `commons-lang3-3.3.2-bin.tar.gz` (their content is same so it doesn't matter which one you will chose).

When you download it unpack it and you will find `commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar` which contains binaries of all classes described at

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html

---

### Usage

Now to use classes from this library you simply need to include it in your classpath so JVM or compiler would know where to look for this new classes. You can do it for instance by using command

```
javac -cp path/to/external.jar MyClass.java
```

(`external.jar` will also need to be part of classpath) which compiles code from `MyClass.java`. Code from this file can use all classes from downloaded `lang` library. All you need to do is use `import name.of.WantedClass` (just like you would import other classes like `java.util.Random`)

Example of code using `StringUtils.repeat`

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class MyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = StringUtils.repeat("Foo", 4);
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Now to execute such code you will also need to inform JVM where to look for not standard class which was used here `StringUtils` so you will again have to use `-cp path/to/external.jar` so your command can look like

```
javac -cp path/to/external.jar MyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. There is nothing like "the download link", but. `org.apache.commons` can be downloaded at [commons.apache.org](http://commons.apache.org). To reverse the package-name is a good point for starting.
2. Anywhere you want. What you will need is to specify the class-path. Most people create a lib-folder and put all used libraries in there. `java MyClass -cp lib/*.jar`

But it would be better (if you have more or bigger projects), if you use build tools like [gradle](http://gradle.org) or [maven](http://maven.org). Booth will let you specifiy some kind of library id and download all needed libs with their dependencies.

**update**

I would start with an IDE. I know, there are a lot of people (coming from other languages, than Java) who don't like them, but it will help to start. You should use an IDE or a command-line build tool (like mentioned above)