# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while running a jar file on windows 8

Tags: java, windows-8, jar

When I am giving the following command

```
java -Xmx1500m -jar myApp.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Throwable Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference
        at bc.c.Util.process(Util.java:135)
        at bc.m.TabularReader$CSVReader.<init>(TabularReader.java:68)
        at bc.m.TabularReader.<init>(TabularReader.java:37)
        at bc.c.Spread2db.main(Spread2db.java:244)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference
        at bc.m.TabularReader$CSVReader.<init>(TabularReader.java:64)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.supercsv.prefs.CsvPreference
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

I guess that this is due to the supercsv which is not getting included properly in the class path.

Please help me fixing this error.

Comment: you did not specify `org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference` class or a jar file with it inside in the class path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the path to the `CsvPreference` class. This is done using the `-cp` flag.

Try

```
java -Xmx1500m -cp pathToCsvPreference -jar myApp.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Comment: I have used the following command
`java -Xmx500m -jar -cp org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreferenc myApp.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9`

but I am getting the following error
`Error: Could not find or load main class myApp.jar`

Comment: Ah, I accidently split your `-jar` command. Try again like I wrote now.

Comment: Still I am getting the same error
`Throwable Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference`

Comment: @Suvendu is `org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference` path to your `myApp.jar` file with `CsvPreferenc` class? It looks more like package than system directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `super-csv jar` and all the required jars in your class path before running this java program. you have two options to do that:

1. You can set it using system classpath by set `CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;<path/to/super-csv jar>;<path to other jars individually>`
2. You can specify it using `-cp` Option while executing Java command

Comment: Hi, I am also having the same error. I did what you instructed, but I am having the same error

Comment: @Anand Please tell us more about your code and hpw are you running it.

Comment: I have a jar file named app.jar, I was trying to run it using the command:

`java -Xmx1500m  -jar app.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 `

But I got an error. I followed your instruction but still I am gettting the error... please suggest

Comment: @Anand You need to say how exactly you tried to run your application and what kind of error you get. I suggest creating separate question which would describe your problem and if you want leave a link to this answer description of what you ware trying to do.

Comment: I had previously discussed about this same error: Please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203671/getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-on-windows-8

But I didn't get any solution from there.

Comment: @Anand I hope you and Suvendu are two persons working on same project because (if I am not mistaken) using two accounts by same person is not allowed on SO. Anyway maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24002036/1393766) (Usage part) will help a little.

Comment: @Anand Check if you are having super-csv jar in your classpath by `echo %CLASSPATH%`